# How to update multiple rows with multiple names in a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to update multiple columns and multiple rows in a single form but the name of inputs are arrays and the form looks like this:

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM reservationmenutable where id > 1"; 
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();
$statement->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$result = $statement->fetchAll();

    echo '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">';
        echo "<thead><b>Other services: </b></thead><br>";
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>Ticket</th>";
            echo "<th>Rate</th>";
            echo "<th>Toggle Availability // 1 = on, 0 = off </th>";
            echo "<th>testheading </th>";


        echo "</tr>";       

        echo "<tbody>";

            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {

                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' placeholder='{$value['service']}' size='35' name='service_id[{$value['id']}]' ></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='number' placeholder='{$value['service_price']}' size='5' name='service_price_id[{$value['id']}]' ></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='{$value['availability']}'  name='availability_id[{$value['id']}]'</td>";    
                echo "<td><input type='text' value='availability_id[{$value['id']}]'  name='' 
                          <input type='hidden' value=''  name='hidden_id[{$value['id']}]'>  

                </td>"; 


                echo "</tr>";

            }

        echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

And this is what I'm trying to do on my update page:

```
<?php 

session_start();

include ('../../class/connection.php');

$sql = "UPDATE reservationmenutable SET (service = ?, service_price = ?, availability = ? ) WHERE id = ?";
$arr_value = [
    $_POST["service_id[]"],
    $_POST["service_price_id[]"],
    $_POST["availability_id[]"],
    $_POST["hidden_id[]"],

];
$statement = $conn->prepare($sql);
$result = $statement->execute($arr_value);
// $result->rowCount();

if($result){
    echo "successfully updated.";
}else{
    echo "error.";
}
```

It's an array I know, but I don't know how I should go about it.

p.s: I'm still a newbie

Comment: what you get currently when u execute?

Comment: Are you asking individual update or group update?

Comment: @KarthikeyanVivekanandhan group update

Comment: Use Foreach or for loop iteration and where is submit button?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile an error, specifically:  Undefined index: service_id[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\processing\admin\adm_services_ctrl_update.php on line 11 , all four posts are error.. availability, hidden and price. they're array, i dont know how to deal with it.. i've seen foreach but im confused on how to implement it on my code

Comment: @KarthikeyanVivekanandhan i didnt include the entire form.. but i have a submit button, i know how to update individual strings but NOT arrays..

Comment: the linked solution is ugly but it works the way you made your form

Comment: @YourCommonSense i know.. it sucks when you dont know what you're doing. i'll try to get better